# Noxim simulator installation: fatal error

Tags: 14.04

In order to run Network on chip simulator form Github called "noxim" , I am getting a fatal error in the last step (build noxim) when I am trying to type "make" and sincerely don't fully understand:

```
saliha@ubuntu:~/Downloads/noxim-master/bin$ make
g++ -O3 -Wall -DSC_NO_WRITE_CHECK --std=c++11   -I../src -isystem   libs/systemc-2.3.1a/include -Ilibs/yaml-cpp/include -c ../src/Stats.cpp -o   build/Stats.o
In file included from ../src/Stats.h:17:0,
         from ../src/Stats.cpp:11:
../src/DataStructs.h:14:21: fatal error: systemc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <systemc.h>
             ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:43: recipe for target 'build/Stats.o' failed
make: *** [build/Stats.o] Error 1
```

I have respected all the steps in INSTALL.txt including C++ compiler installation, YAML installation, SystemC installation until Build noxim.

The only difference between noxim guide prerequisites and what I found is the SystemC version "systemc 2.3.1(including in INSTALL.txt) and systemc 2.3.1a (what i found)"

Comment: When you ran `make install` as part of the SystemC installation, where did in the filesystem did it install *to*? did you run that step as `root` (with `sudo`) or as your regular user?

Comment: With a regular user as shown  in the code above. I used mkdir to create a new directory objdir then I executed cd objdir including in systemc-2.3.1a

Comment: Unless you installed systemc into `noxim-master/bin/libs` you will probably need to open up the `noxim-master/bin/Makefile` in a text editor, and change the `SYSTEMC := libs/systemc-2.3.1` line to reflect the actual path where you installed systemc (including changing `2.3.1` to `2.3.1a`). Likely the same applies to the next line `libs/yaml-cpp`.

Comment: there is no directory called libs in all three parts, thus I have changed path to libs/systemc2.3.1a